# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent foreach loop

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm in a controller for Laravel 5.2 and am trying to iterate through an eloquent collection of invoice_items, which would translate to something like order items. So, the invoice would act as the order, have it's ordered items (invoice_item), and the invoice_items would list all of the products ordered (product).

Here's what I have:

```
$id = $value; //from param
$invoice = Invoice::where('id', $id)->get();
$invoice_items = Invoice_item::all()->where('invoice_id', $invoice[0]->id);

$contact = Contact::where('id', $invoice[0]->contact_id)->get();

foreach($invoice_items as $item) {
    $products = Product::all()->where('id', $item->product_id);
}
```

I'm attempting to pull all of the products from that specific invoice (via invoice items), which in this specific case should be two, different products.

What's happening, is when I iterate through using that loop, it's adding the same product twice, whereas it should be adding each product once. Is my logic just wrong here? Or do I need to look at my relationships again or something?

Comment: Try `get()` instead of `all()` when using `where()`.

Comment: get() gives the same output, unfortunately. Thanks for the quick response, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your queries to:

```
$invoice = Invoice::where('id', $id)->get();
$invoice_items = Invoice_item::where('invoice_id', $invoice[0]->id)->get();

$contact = Contact::where('id', $invoice[0]->contact_id)->get();

foreach($invoice_items as $item) {
    $products = Product::where('id', $item->product_id)->get();
}
```

An easier way may be to add a items relation to the InvoiceItems model. E.g.:

```
public function items()
{
  $this->hasOne('Items');
}
```

Then you can get all the Items from Invoice_item using:

```
return $invoice_items->items;
```

---

You can also try:

```
$invoice = Invoice::where('id', $id)->get();
$invoice_items = Invoice_item::where('invoice_id', $invoice[0]->id)->get()->lists('product_id');

$contact = Contact::where('id', $invoice[0]->contact_id)->get();

$products = Product::whereIn('id', $invoice_items)->get();
```

Hopefully, `$products` will then contain a collection of products for that invoice. No need for a foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback — I'm going to try that other relationship when I get a chance to see if that will work. However, changing the query within the foreach loop still doesn't work. What's actually happening, is the query is only pulling one product within the loop. Thus, the $products object only holds the last product, or the product pulled from the second iteration. I think the only logical thing to do is push it into an array. I just wanted to continually work with an object for simplicity sake.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another example you can try, without need for foreach loop. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I made a temp invoice_items variable just because I still needed full access to those objects in the view, but using the ->lists() method on the now temp worked out great. Yay! No need for arrays. Thanks again!